# 2x 'loop' and 1x 'Do Until' -> cannot run the macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a simple algorithm that will generate Sudoku game table. I have encountered the following problem. The main part of my code is the Do until loop. But I cannot run the macro when there are two 'loop' phrases. Could anyone tell me why is that? And is there any way to overcome this problem? I would very grateful for any tips. I would also appreciate very much (as I am new to the forum) if you could let me know if my post is vague or doesn't match your expectations.
The code is as follows: (moments when there is a problem are marked with a comment)
    Sub MAIN()

```
Dim a, r, c, V As Integer

r = 2
c = 2
Do Until r = 11 And c = 2
a = Sheets("LIST").Columns("B").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows,  LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row - 1

V = Int(a * Rnd + 1)
Sheets("GAME").Cells(r, c).Value = V
If V = 5 Then 'This condition is a test-condition. In the final version of code there should be more sophisticated condition.
Sheets("LIST").Range("B" & V - 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
Loop '(this is the first loop)
End If

If c = 10 Then
r = r + 1
c = 2
Else
c = c + 1
End If
Sheets("LIST").Cells(2, 2).Value = 1
Sheets("LIST").Cells(2, 3).Value = 2
Sheets("LIST").Cells(2, 4).Value = 3
Sheets("LIST").Cells(2, 5).Value = 4
Sheets("LIST").Cells(2, 6).Value = 5
Sheets("LIST").Cells(2, 7).Value = 6
Sheets("LIST").Cells(2, 8).Value = 7
Sheets("LIST").Cells(2, 9).Value = 8
Sheets("LIST").Cells(2, 10).Value = 9
Loop '(this is the second loop)
End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't closed your first end if properly, the loop possibly should come after the end if not before. Youre only setting up one loop so how are you expecting to be able to use `loop` twice? you know that `a, r, c,` are Variants and only `V` is an Integer?

Comment: Right off the top, I can see that you have an `If` statement the `Loop` of the first `Do` loop. This should probably be completely evaluated within the `Loop...Do` block. Indenting might make these types of issues easier to spot visually

Comment: Thanks guys! One can truly rely on you! Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick note too (for reference), you can save a fair amount of typing by using the `With... End With` construct:

```
'...
With Sheets("LIST")
    .Cells(2, 2) = 1
    .Cells(3, 2) = 2
    .Cells(4, 2) = 3
    '...
End With
```

Then, if you were feeling really wild, you could populate your sodoku square with a `For...Next` loop:

```
'...
Dim SizeOfSquare As Long, Index As Long
SizeOfSquare = 9

With Sheets("LIST")
    For Index = 1 To SizeOfSquare
        .Cells(Index + 1, 2) = Index
    Next Index
End With
```

Being lazy is not always a bad thing!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, secodn after Ive posted it I came up with a solution!
I am sorry that I have spamed the forum. This is the code amended:
(I will leave it here in case someone would have such a stupid problem as myself :) )

```
Sub MAIN()

Dim a, r, c, V As Integer

r = 2
c = 2
Do Until r = 11 And c = 2
a = Sheets("LIST").Columns("B").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows,     LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row - 1

V = Int(a * Rnd + 1)
Sheets("GAME").Cells(r, c).Value = V
If V = 5 Then
Sheets("LIST").Range("B" & V - 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp

Else

If c = 10 Then
r = r + 1
c = 2
Else
c = c + 1
End If
Sheets("LIST").Cells(2, 2).Value = 1
Sheets("LIST").Cells(3, 2).Value = 2
Sheets("LIST").Cells(4, 2).Value = 3
Sheets("LIST").Cells(5, 2).Value = 4
Sheets("LIST").Cells(6, 2).Value = 5
Sheets("LIST").Cells(7, 2).Value = 6
Sheets("LIST").Cells(8, 2).Value = 7
Sheets("LIST").Cells(9, 2).Value = 8
Sheets("LIST").Cells(10, 2).Value = 9
End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: At the risk of being redundant, this solution is workable, but IMHO the lack of indentation was the real culprit, as indicated by @Dan.
You've fixed the specific problem you were having, but haven't addressed the underlying cause: lack of proper indentation.

Comment: Shucks, thanks @LimaNightHawk. It's funny but sometimes little visual cues can save your bacon!